# Different T Test outcomes between Excel and R and between T.Test of original dataset and MRE for Stack

Tags: r, excel, statistics, t-test

I'll say up front that my understanding of both statistics and R is poor, so this is likely basic, fundamental knowledge I'm lacking. I have a dataset with Subject, Timepoint (Before or After), Category (Low, Medium, or High), and Percentage. It's only eight subjects, and it's a before and after measure of what percentage of time the subjects spent in the three different categories. I'm just trying to run paired sample t-tests for each category.

I ran t-tests for each category in Google Sheets and Excel and received the same p-value, but when I ran them in R, I got a different result. When I ran it in R, I simply subset the original dataset by category `LowDF <- mydata %>% subset(Category == "Low")` and then ran `t.test(Percentage ~ Timepoint, data = LowDF, paired = TRUE)` for each. However, when I created an identical dataframe of `lowDF` as an MRE for Stack and ran it, I got the same result as Excel and Sheets and a different result to the one from analyzing the subset of the original dataset. I printed the dataframes in the console and they are identical. I'm not even sure how to provide the data for reference.

Like I said, my understanding of basic statistics is poor - I have a vague idea about whether this has to do with factors or multiple comparisons. If you need the original dataset, please let me know how I can share that since I can't reproduce the problem with a custom/manual MRE.

Comment: Without seeing your data _and_ the output from the different tests, it's impossible to be definitive, and this question may well get closed as a result.  One obvious potential reason for the difference is that one version of the test may used a pooled estimate of variance and the other not.  You can include input data using `dput` and the output simply by pasting into your question.  There is a vast amount of advice on how to do that on this site: not least at the top of each page under "Learn more"...